# Meu modulo Lightbox que inseri no Angular não funciona, como fazer?

Tags: html, css, node.js, angular, configuração

Bom eu instalei esse modulo Lightbox com o comando `npm install lightbox2 --save` conforme o site: [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) até aí tudo bem.

Após eu coloquei os caminhos no arquivo angular-cli.json conforme exemplos que pesquisei na net e ficou assim:

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/lightbox2/dist/css/lightbox.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/lightbox2/dist/js/lightbox.js"
  ],
```

Após eu montei meu HTML conforme o indicado no site [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/):

```
<a href="../../assets/img/teste.jpg" data-lightbox="teste.jpg" class="imagem" style="background-image: url('../../assets/img/1.jpg')">
    <img src="../../assets/img/teste.jpg" style="display: none">
</a>
```

Bom, aí depois fui tentar visualizar na página o efeito desejado (conforme o site [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)) não funcionou, agora eu não sei se falta mais alguma coisa ou tem algo errado no que fiz?

Comment: É bom você incluir a versão do agular que está utilizando, e o código de inicialização do lightbox, onde quer que você tenha inserido.

Comment: A versão é a 5.2.9, do angular cli 1.7.3 e a do node 8.11.1. Nos links que deixei na descrição tem como eu instalei o lightbox, a pasta (estrutura) dele foi parar na pasta node_modulos? A inicialização da qual tu te referes creio que seja a ultima parte da minha descrição, aquilo deveria funcionar!